# C# Enum - Guessing Flags given an int input

Tags: c#, enums, flags

Let's suppose we have the following Enum of Flags:

```
[Flags]
    public enum Animals
    {
        Cow = 1,

        Duck = 2,

        Goose = 4
    }
```

Now, given this Enum, we want to specify a function with an int as the input, and given this number, we want to return an array with the animals that this number contains.

For example, if we receive as input the number 7, we know we have a Cow, a Duck and a Goose, because 4+2+1 = 7.

For any number of animals presented in this enum, how can we determine which animals are contained in that number?

Comment: Any reason why you're using/passing an integer, as opposed to `var animals = Animals.Cow | Animals.Duck | Animals.Goose`?

Comment: Convert the integer back to an enum and do a bitwise OR for the flags you want to check, or use `Enum.HasFlag`

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the user inputs 8? 2 geese? 8 cows?

Comment: This is essentially searching. Select a search algorithm and construct test cases - since there will probably be more than one answer.

Comment: @Sayse I would return 1 goose, 1 duck, 2 cows and a chicken, just to confuse the enemy :-)

Comment: @dcastro, I was given the task to guess which members of the enum are contained in a given number, since it is passed from the front end to the back end, it cannot be an enum already.

Comment: @Hallaghan you can cast the int to `Animals` and use the strongly typed enum instead of `int`

Comment: Is this an assignment by any chance? It looks strikingly similar to the example on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @WillJenkins, I used Animals in this case because I didn't want to use the real enum we are using in our Application. It's not by any chance an assignment, but I admit bit operations aren't my specialty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic version - not overly fast and could probably be improved...

```
void Main()
{
    var flags = Ext.GetFlags<Animal>(7);
    flags.Dump();
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(int flags)
    where T : struct    
    {
        return typeof(T).GetEnumValues().Cast<T>()
            .Where(a => ((dynamic)(T)(object)flags).HasFlag(a)).ToList();
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Animal
{
    Cow =1,
    Duck = 2,
    Goose = 4,
    Dog = 8
}
```

Comment: Those stray Dogs get everywhere!

Answer (score 6):

```
public static IEnumerable<Animals> GetAnimals(int i)
{
    var animals = (Animals) i;

    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(animals.GetType()))
        if (animals.HasFlag(value))
            yield return (Animals) value;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yydUE2

Comment: This could easily be made generic

Comment: try sending 8 to this function. it returns an empty IEnumerable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Right, because 8 is 1000 in binary. And since the 3 most significant bits are 0, then it doesn't contain any of the flags. I would say that's the expected behaviour.

Comment: @dcastro I'm not so sure, that's something the OP should answer. his question suggests otherwise (I'm talking, of course, about this part: `1+2+4=7`)

Answer (score 1):

As other have said, there is not a single answer for the vast majority of cases but given you example I will assume you want a greedy guessing algorithm to return the minimum number of larger-valued animals:

```
void Main()
{

    int test = 21;

    var allAnimals = (Animal[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Animal));
    var ordered = allAnimals.OrderByDescending(x => x);

    var animals = ordered.Aggregate(new List<Animal>(), (agg, ani) => { 
        if (test > 0) {
            int number = (int)(test / (int)ani);
            agg.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(ani, number));
            test -= number * (int)ani;
        }
        return agg;
    });

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", animals.Select(a=>a.ToString())));
}

[Flags]
public enum Animal
{
    Cow = 1,

    Duck = 2,

    Goose = 4
}
```

Comment: Obviously this could be packaged up as a method, more just a proof of concept and maybe I misunderstood the question but this is an alternative none the less.